# Dompdf related issues style, link, table goes out and related issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dompdf

Q. 1:
**DomPDF table goes out of pdf from print report if table is wider**
I am using dompdf and it works fine for small wider tables but it goes out of pdf page when it's too much wider so any solution is there I have looked at many places but couldn't find the solution.

Please find attach photo of issue:
[image]

**Q: 2: Is Dompdf Support Bootstrap:**

I have a bootstrap layout which doesn't seem supportable as I have added all required bootstrap css on top of the page but they are not working like hidden-xs which I really wanted to apply if the table is too wider then hide few columns like above Q-1 case.

**Q: 3: Color not applied even specified in table inline Style:**

Ok, so now my turn to explain how I did the code before Q-3 so I have one page called index.php where I have a table and all css styles on top. Now I specify table inside div like following:

```
<div id="htmlData"><table class="my bootstrap table"></table></div>
```

So now how I print things well I wrote one script on the same index.php page:

```
<script>function printout(){ $.ajax({ POST: '../dompdf/print_report.php'  })}
```

Now this print_report.php file contain the code which will like the following:

Print_report.php:

```
    <?php 
    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
    ob_start(); 
?>
<html>
<head> 
    <link href="**if I define any link path like http://bla.com/index.css - then it not work so I define styles on page level**" ....> 
    <link/>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    echo $_POST['htmlData']; //which I send through ajax 
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$html = ob_get_clean()
...rest of the code.....to print and save pdf to a file
?>;
```

However,  Please help me out in this option as I believe DOMPDF is the best on net and I really don't want to lose using it so if anyone  out there any help  me than. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: [dompdf does not yet support Bootstrap styling](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/631)

Comment: Also, table layout is a little glitchy and table cells won't shrink below the width of unwrappable text. dompdf can't really do a max width on table cell content because of this.

Comment: Linked stylesheets are fine, but whether or not dompdf can load them depends entirely on your configuration (dompdf, php), the reference links, and how you load your document.

Comment: Add a sample document (simplified to the actual issue if possible) and we might be able to provide an answer specific to your problem.

Comment: Hi Brian thank you so much but I have resolved it everything and my reports are now working so perfect. As I wanted to help others I'll add descriptive answer very soon with some screenshots may be as I think it's really needed for others as after I struggled, I really don't want any fresh developer do that :) but thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi @Jimil, Can you please help me, how you resolve your Q. 1: DomPDF table goes out of pdf from print report if table is wider

Comment: Hi @herr not sure where I've placed the code as it's a really old post but what I remember was implementing pdf in landscape view and also adjusting the font, width, borders, hiding unnecessary data on pdf view, and also try to reduce the by default margins of pdf. I am sorry as I don't have access the old code anymore.